# tableView setEditing causes cellForRow to not be called prematurely

Tags: iphone, uitableview, orientation

I have an issue with a View Controller which is loaded from a NIB. In this NIB I have 2 views, a landscape and portrait. When willAnimateForRotation occurs I i set

```
// willAnimateForRotation..
if (isLandscape) {
    self.view = self.viewLandscape;
}
else {
    self.view = self.portraitView;
}
```

in the beginning I set both tables to editing mode:

```
// viewDidLoad
[self.tableViewPortrait setEditing:YES animated:NO];
[self.tableViewLandscape setEditing:YES animated:NO]; // *
```

// *
I am pretty sure this line is causing cellForRow to be called on tableViewLandscape at this point, instead of when i set self.tableView = self.tableViewLandscape

It only happens the first time, if I perform 2 orientation changes it will load the items into the tableView correctly.

i dont want to do a [self.tableView reloadData] in orientation change.. that would be redundant.

can anyone see a more graceful way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, best I could come up with is:

```
//willAnimateToRotation..
if (!self.tableViewLandscape.editing)
{
    [self.tableViewLandscape setEditing:YES animated:NO];
}
```

its a cheap hack but can't think of a more correct solution.